# Do you know how I can create backup files automatically?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I backup files a few times a day on Ubuntu/Linux with the command `tar -cpvzf ~/Backup/backup_file_name.tar.gz directory_to_backup/`. I want to create a script that will create the file name automatically - check:

```
~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_a.tar.gz
```

if it exists, if it exists then replace "_a" with "_b" and then checks all the letters up to z. Create the first backup file that doesn't exist. If all the files up to z exist then add "_1" to the file name (with "_z") and check all the numbers until the file doesn't exist. Never change an existing file but only create new backup files. Do you know how to create such a script?

Comment: Why not add hour, minute, and second to the filename?

Comment: @LutzHorn it's a nice idea, but I prefer shorter file names such as backup_file_name_2014-02-11_a. I can see the time by the time the file was saved (with `ll`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. I created the file `~/scripts/backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

working_dir=`pwd`
backupname=""

if [ -z "$backupname" ]; then
    for l in {a..z} ; do
    if [ ! -f ~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}.tar.gz ]; then
        backupname=~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}.tar.gz
        break
    fi
    done
fi

if [ -z "$backupname" ]; then
    l="z"
    for (( i = 1 ; i <= 1000; i++ )) do
    if [ ! -f ~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}_${i}.tar.gz ]; then
        backupname=~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}_${i}.tar.gz
        break
    fi
    done
fi

if [ ! -z "$backupname" ]; then
    cd ~/projects/
    ~/scripts/tar.sh $backupname directory_to_backup/
    cd $working_dir
else
    echo "Oops! can't create backup file name."
fi

exit
```

The file `~/scripts/tar.sh` contains this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo "Oops! backup file was already here."
    exit
fi
tar -cpvzf $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

Now I just have to type `~/scripts/backup.sh` and the script backs up my files.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
for l in {a..z} ; do
    [[ -f ~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}.tar.gz ]] && continue
    export backupname=-f ~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_${l}.tar.gz && break
done

# test if $backupname is properly set, what if `z` is used? I'm leaving this to you
# then backup as usual

tar -cpvzf $backupname directory_to_backup/
```

This iterates over the letters and if the required file exists skips setting the `backupname` variable.

Comment: there should be soem exit from the loop, otherwise it will create names from backward...

Answer (score -1):

Create a script which saves file with date like,

~/Backup/backup_file_name_${date}.tar.gz

and run that script a cron job if you want to take backup after some specific interval or run it manually if you dont have such requirement.

Comment: that will create backup files with date appended at the end. you dont need to check a-z sequence.though you take backup every second (imaginary case) then also file name will be different. that will solve your issue according to me.